# How to make UUPS upgradeable contracts modular

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts, upgrading, contract-upgrading, design-patterns

I have the following contract:

```
import { UUPSUpgradeable } from "@openzeppelin-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import { OwnableUpgradeable } from "@openzeppelin-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract One is UUPSUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    uint256 public var1;
    uint256 public var2;

  function initialize() public initializer {
    __Ownable_init();
    __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
  }

    function setVar1(uint256 _var1) public {
        var1 = _var1;
    }

    function setVar2(uint256 _var1) public {
        var2 = _var2;
    }

  function _authorizeUpgrade(address) internal virtual override onlyOwner {}

}
```

I deploy a proxy with `hardhat-upgrades`, then realize that `setVar2()` and `var2` would be better placed in a separate file to make the contract more modular. So I create a `Utils` contract that I will inherit from.

My intuition is that I should be able to do this:

```
contract Utils{
    uint256 public var2;

    function setVar2(uint256 _var2) public {
        var2 = _var2;
    }
}
```

But then, wouldn't lose the upgradeability of everything in `Utils`? If I want to preserve the upgradeability of what I have going on in `contract One` would I need to do deploy *another** proxy? (for `Utils`) resulting in the following code?

```
import { UUPSUpgradeable } from "@openzeppelin-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import { OwnableUpgradeable } from "@openzeppelin-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract Utils is UUPSUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    uint256 public var2;

  function initialize() public initializer {
    __Ownable_init();
    __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
  }

    function setVar2(uint256 _var2) public {
        var2 = _var2;
    }

  function _authorizeUpgrade(address) internal virtual override onlyOwner {}

}
```

then update `One` to have:

```
contract One is Utils {
    uint256 public var1;

    function setVar1(uint256 _var1) public {
        var1 = _var1;
    }

  function _authorizeUpgrade(address) internal virtual override onlyOwner {}

}
```

**Questions:**

- Do I need to add an initializer and inherit `UUPSUpgradeable` and `OwnableUpgradeable` to `Utils`  to maintain upgradeability?
- In the latest version of `contract One`  ... do I need `_authorizeUpgrade`? Since it's already inherited from `Utils`?
- Is it ok that in the latest version of `contract One` I got rid of the initializer?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, very well laid out.

1. Inheriting `UUPSUpgradeable` and `OwnableUpgradeable` from `Utils` like you have done is the way to go. When building an upgradeable contract you should build in upgradeability from the base contract that is being inherited from, which in this case is `Utils`. You're not deploying another proxy, you're using the same proxy for `One` and `Utils` with this pattern.
2. Nope, you don't need `_authorizeUpgrade` in `One`. Since you're inheriting from `Utils` and the method is public you will be able to call it from the address to which `One` is deployed.
3. Yep, you technically don't need it in `One` as you're not doing anything in the context of that contract, however I would personally include it.

I would add this to `One`:

```
function initialize() public initializer {
    Utils.initialize();
}
```

and then modify utils:

```
function initialize() public onlyInitializing {
   [same as before]
}
```

As a side note I would also reserve a set of storage slots in `Utils` so that you have the freedom to add more variables during an upgrade. With your current code, if you wanted to reserve another storage slot in `Utils` at an upgrade, you would actually write over `var1` in `One`. To reserve storage slots, add the following under `var2` in `Utils` (to reserve 49 slots as an example):

```
uint256[49] __gap;
```